# C++: Return type of std::tie with std::ignore

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, tuples, undefined-behavior

I am wondering if the C++11 standard gives any requirement about the *type* of the `std::tuple` returned by `std::tie` when some arguments are `std::ignore`.

More specifically, can I assume that:

1. `decltype(std::tie(42, std::ignore))` is not the same as `decltype(std::tie(std::ignore, 42))`
2. `decltype(std::tie(42, std::ignore))` is not the same as `decltype(std::tie(42))`
3. `decltype(std::tie(std::ignore, 42))` is not the same as `decltype(std::tie(42))`
4. `decltype(std::tie(std::ignore, std::ignore))` is not the same as `decltype(std::tie(std::ignore))`

In other words, from the type perspective, does the generated tuple behaves as a tuple which has type `decltype(std::ignore)` for all template arguments that match `std::ignore` by position?

Comment: undefined behaviour?  Maybe unspecified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) returns a `std::tuple<T&...>` where `T...` are the types that are given to it.
`std::ignore` has an unspecified type, but it will still appear in the `tuple` according to where you specified it in `std::tie`.

If if makes you feel better, you could include in your code somewhere:

```
    int n;
    auto i = std::tie(std::ignore, n);
    auto j = std::tie(n, std::ignore);
    auto k = std::tie(n);
    static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(i), decltype(j)>::value, "");
    static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(i), decltype(k)>::value, "");
    static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(j), decltype(k)>::value, "");
```

and so on for whatever combinations you are explicitly using.  This way compilation will fail if your assumption is invalid.

Comment: So, as long as I don't make any assumptions about the type of std::ignore, I can treat all those tuples above as of different type (I need them just for specialization purposes)? Additionally, is it safe to forward a `std::ignore` using `decltype(std::ignore)&&` and `std::forward`, e.g. imagine you subclass a `std::tuple`?

Comment: @leden I don't see why you couldn't forward an `ignore`, but I don't think you can assume that you can assign it to another `ignore`.

Comment: Three is a contradiction in your reasoning, `std::ignore` being unspecified specifically means that the Standard does not mandate for it to be different than any other type; and therefore it would be Standard compliant for `std::ignore` to be `int` (although it would be dumb)

Comment: @MatthieuM. That makes sense, I think the Standard can give restrictions or list acceptable possibilities on unspecified things (it explicitly says it can for _unspecified behavior_) but it doesn't do that for `std::ignore`.  I don't know if you are allowed to say that it must be different from any other type you could give a `tuple` in order for the compiler to be able to separate it out.

Comment: Problems like this make me desire the 'standard library of evil'.

Comment: @leden If you are doing it just for specialization purposes, why not use an empty class with a unique name? Then you know what its type is, and it will be distinct from other types.

Comment: @Tim Seguine: Actually, I want to subclass tuple and then specialize cases like `<ignore, T>`, `<T, ignore>` etc..

@MatthieuM: Let's assume that the type of `std::ignore` is not `int`... With that assumption in mind, are the examples above still undefined behavior?

Comment: Subclassing standard containers is usually considered a bad thing™. It isn't the only reason not to, but they don't, for example, have virtual destructors. As for `std::ignore` since the type is unspecified, you can't make any assumptions about its distinctness. It may be distinct on some platforms but not others. Relying on certain behavior is not going to be portable and might blow up in your face.