# Wrapping std::ignore

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, wrapper

I'm working on a custom library. So far, I've wrapped std::tuple and std::tie into my own myOwn::Tuple and myOwn::tie. They function the same way that std::tuple and std::tie do. I'd like to do something similar with std::ignore.

So far, I've written the following:

```
namespace myOwn
{
     auto
     tilde()
     -> decltype(std::ignore)
     {
         return std::ignore;
     }
}
```

My only issue is that I now have to use myOwn::tilde() with parentheses. I'd like to be able to use this as myOwn::tilde. So far, all I've read on std::ignore is how to use it,

Here: [Possible implementations of std::ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822100/possible-implementations-of-stdignore)

Here: [Requirements for std::ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721884/requirements-for-stdignore)

And here: [C++: Return type of std::tie with std::ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994074/c-return-type-of-stdtie-with-stdignore)

I've tried using

```
typedef std::ignore tilde
```

but this was not successful. Any help would be appreciated. This question could useful to anyone else trying to wrap objects.

Comment: What do you think `std::ignore` is? A *type* or an *object* ?

Comment: Why are you wrapping std things !?

Comment: Is there some problem with `auto tilde = std::ignore;` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not need to modify `std::ignore`, and simply want to rename it, then

```
decltype(std::ignore) &tilde = std::ignore;
```

at namespace scope should do what you need.

`std::ignore` is not guaranteed to be `DefaultConstructible` or `CopyAssignable`, so it cannot be portably constructed or copied, but we can save a reference to it. The type of this `tilde` is `decltype(std::ignore) &`, but since `std::tie` takes references, this should function the same as `std::ignore`.

Comment: or `decltype(std::ignore)& tilde = std::ignore;` to create an alias instead of another copy.  The above presumes that `std::ignore`'s type can be constructed by you.

Comment: @Yakk Good point, I edited my answer. You may want to make an answer with that correction.

Comment: it is imho just a refinement of tthe above answer.  Fix this one, and I don't have to!